# incompatible type: cannot convert void to an int

Tags: java, int, void

I created this method in my `BankAccount` class and would like to call it in a different class called `Demo`. But when I try and call the second class I get an error saying:

> incompatible types: void cannot be converted to an int.

```
public void makeDeposit(int amount) { 
    if ( account != AccountType.LOAN ) {
        if ( balance >= 0) {
            balance = (balance + amount); 
        }
    }
}
```

So how could I call this method into another class and convert it into an `int`?

The code that throws the above error is:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void SavingsAccount() {
        BankAccount acc = new BankAccount(0, 0.5);
        int hi = acc.makeDeposit(100);
     } 
}
```

By the way, I am using blueJ, if it matters.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about essential language features that are too broad to be explained in a single SO answer. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a tutorial, class or good book.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: You showed us the method, but you haven't showed us the code that gets the error (i.e., the code that calls your method.  It's hard to say what the error is if you don't show us the code.

Comment: public class Demo
{
    public static void SavingsAccount() 
    {
        BankAccount acc = new BankAccount(0, 0.5);
        int hi = acc.makeDeposit(100); 
    }

Comment: @KhaledKabalan If `makeDeposit` is required to return nothing, what do you expect is the value of `hi` after that method call?

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: A good start is to think about, what you want with `hi`? What should it represent? If you know that, then change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The way your calling the method requires it to return an int. You are probably assigning the return value to something. You need to change the method signature to say `public int makeDeposit(int amount)` and have it return an integer.

Alternatively you could change your code not to assign the return value of that method.

Comment: This answer may or may not be helpful. `makeDeposit` may also very well be void due to spec of an assignment.

Comment: my prof made it mandatory to make it a void

Comment: @KhaledKabalan well, then don't use it like this: `int number = makeDeposit(amount);`. This requires a return type of `makeDeposit` to assign that returned value the variable `number`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method needs a return type - it should be

```
public int makeDeposit(int amount)
```

This is really part of the language and you should look it up rather than asking here...

Comment: This answer may or may not be helpful. `makeDeposit` may also very well be void due to spec of an assignment.

Comment: my prof made it mandatory to make it a void

Comment: then lookup passing by reference and passing by value.

you want to call it a procedure given a variable and manipulate the variable passed in. Presumably you need to set the value of amount before the method ends.